# HTTP 409 Error while using RestTemplate for consuming two RESTful API - Solved

Tags: java, rest, spring-boot, http, resttemplate

**Solved!**
One of APIs had some restriction on query interval, i.e. minimum 60 seconds. I was trying to call the API faster than it was expected.

However, the API should return HTTP 429 error instead of 409.

I have a simple Spring Boot project with a scheduled task as follows:

```
@Autowired
private RestTemplate restTemplate;

@Bean
public RestTemplate restTemplate(RestTemplateBuilder builder) {
    return builder.basicAuthentication(username, password).build();
}


@Scheduled(fixedRate = 10000)
public void getData() throws Exception {

    String realtime_data = restTemplate.getForObject(realtime_addr, String.class);
    log.info(realtime_data);
    String legal_data = restTemplate.getForObject(legal_addr, String.class);
    log.info(legal_data.substring(0,200));
```

I have two different APIs with different addresses and I want to consume them.

But I eventually come across to the following Exception:

> **org.springframework.web.client.HttpClientErrorException$Conflict: 409 Conflict**
>   at
>   org.springframework.web.client.HttpClientErrorException.create(HttpClientErrorException.java:91)
>   ~[spring-web-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]     at
>   org.springframework.web.client.DefaultResponseErrorHandler.handleError(DefaultResponseErrorHandler.java:122)
>   ~[spring-web-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]     at
>   org.springframework.web.client.DefaultResponseErrorHandler.handleError(DefaultResponseErrorHandler.java:102)
>   ~[spring-web-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]     at
>   org.springframework.web.client.ResponseErrorHandler.handleError(ResponseErrorHandler.java:63)
>   ~[spring-web-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]     at
>   org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.handleResponse(RestTemplate.java:778)
>   ~[spring-web-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]     at
>   org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.doExecute(RestTemplate.java:736)
>   ~[spring-web-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]     at
>   org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.execute(RestTemplate.java:670)
>   ~[spring-web-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]     at
>   org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.getForObject(RestTemplate.java:311)
>   ~[spring-web-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]     at
>   ir.pisys.rest.Schedule.reportCurrentTime(Schedule.java:64)
>   ~[classes/:na]    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native
>   Method) ~[na:1.8.0_221]   at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
>   ~[na:1.8.0_221]   at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
>   ~[na:1.8.0_221]   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
>   ~[na:1.8.0_221]   at
>   org.springframework.scheduling.support.ScheduledMethodRunnable.run(ScheduledMethodRunnable.java:84)
>   ~[spring-context-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]     at
>   org.springframework.scheduling.support.DelegatingErrorHandlingRunnable.run(DelegatingErrorHandlingRunnable.java:54)
>   ~[spring-context-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]     at
>   java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Unknown Source)
>   [na:1.8.0_221]    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.runAndReset(Unknown
>   Source) [na:1.8.0_221]    at
>   java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$301(Unknown
>   Source) [na:1.8.0_221]    at
>   java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(Unknown
>   Source) [na:1.8.0_221]    at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
>   [na:1.8.0_221]    at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
>   [na:1.8.0_221]    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) [na:1.8.0_221]

What is the problem?

Comment: 409 is the http status code of the response. You may try to log the body to know if the API called give you some details about this GET conflict (quite strange). or else ask to the server owner why their Api respond 409.

Comment: it may be an Api bug : return 409 instead of 429 which means too many requests (which makes sense for a repeated get method)

Comment: Have you tried to call that endpoint manually (from browser or postman/rest client)? What was the response?

Comment: @boly38 The API has some restrictions on response time. The first one responds every two minutes and the other responds every 60 minutes. But if we call it faster it returns a json with an error code inside. If I comment one of restTemplates and consume only one API, no problem occurs.

Comment: @selindek  I have tried that and everything is OK. The API has some restrictions on response time. The first one responds every two minutes and the other responds every 60 minutes. But if we call it faster it returns a json with an error code inside. If I comment one of restTemplates and consume only one API, no problem occurs.

Comment: One point you didn't get is that your local code is correct. This error code reflect an issue in the API you're consuming. So out of getting API side implementation you/we are unable to know what's wrong, and what 409 means. Please refer to API documentation / support.